# Manga with a main character who is reincarnated in a peaceful world, killed by a bear, then reincarnated again in a darker, more violent world

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, reincarnation

The main character was reincarnated into a peaceful world and got killed by a bear, along with his sister. Then he got reincarnated again in a darker and more violent world.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? Also, can you tell us anything more about the characters or plot? For example, did the MC have any powers or weapons? Did the more violent world have monsters/demons in it, or just violent people? And were there any other notable characters you haven't mentioned?

Comment: https://www.pepcomics.com/nld/hunting-in-another-world-with-my-elf-wife-vol-01?

Comment: Reddit poster looking for the same manga "*the mc is a man he got reincarnated into a peaceful world and then he and his sister got killed by a bear and they got isekaid again in a much worse world and now he travels to find his sister."*

Comment: A correct answer can be accepted by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

Could this be *[Different World Munchkin-The Strongest and Fastest Dungeon Strategy with HP1](https://isekai.fandom.com/wiki/Isekai_Munchkin:_HP1_no_Mama_de_Saikyou_Saisoku_Dungeon_Kouryaku)* (AKA *Isekai Munchkin: HP1 no Mama de Saikyou Saisoku Dungeon Kouryaku)*?

> Depicting the story of a shut-in, Yukito Kirihara, after being reincarnated into another world. His peaceful life with his precious caring sister, Sana, suddenly ends when a beast appears and attacks them, thus reincarnating him into the Ever World. Moreover, knowing that Sana also got reincarnated into the Ever World, for the sake of finding his beloved little sister he begins his journey to another world.
>
> [image]

The creature that kills him and his sister looks a bit like a bear, I guess*.

> [image]

<sub><sub><sup>∗</sup>If you squint and have been drinking.</sub></sub>

Comment: Not exactly like a bear; but one should keep in mind (I almost said "bear") how incredibly scary non-fictional bears before we had firearms. Every bit as scary as werewolves, especially since the bears themselves knew we were more or less defenseless. No one probably thought baby bears were cute, even.